# CSS Hover on hover bug

Tags: css, hover, selector

currently I'm having a problem with the hover selector.[Image Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZCvU.jpg)
The whole idea is that an image of an author can be hovered, when hovered the name and a button are displayed. However I also want to be able to hover the button without the hover from the image to start glitching and dissapearing. I tried `pointer-events: none;` but that doesn't allow me to hover the button or click it.

How can I make the selectors so that everything works and it doesn't but when I try to hover the button or at least when I click it.

Code for the images:

```
&--upper::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    height: 18rem;
    width: 15rem;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
}

&--upper:hover::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

&--upper::before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

}
```

Code for the button:

```
a:link,
a:visited {
    position: absolute;
    color: $color-white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    border: 1px solid $color-white;
    background-color: transparent;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And the structure of the html:

```
        <figure class="author author--upper author--1">
            <img src="img/aleko-konstantinov.jpg" alt="Aleko Konstantinov Photo" class="author__image">
        </figure>
        <div class="details details--upper details--1">
            <span class="first-name first-name--1">Алеко</span>
            <span class="second-name second-name--1">Константинов</span>
            <a href="#" class="details__btn details__btn--1">Прочети</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: can u put it in jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/theLznrm/4/ There you have it. Hope that helps you! However the code is css and not sass, hope thats not a problem!

Comment: Basically, **you can't**. You can only effectively hover one item at a time. In addition, with your current HTML structure, you can't affect your `details` div by hovering the image as there is no parent selector. A structural change is required, at least starting by putting the details div inside the the `figure` so it can be affected by hover of the image.